# Popover with CollectionView on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover, collectionview

I was wondering if there was anyway to use Popover's box when i click an item in a collection View ?

Thanks !

Comment: popover is for ipad, you could probably put tags for ipad not for iphone if this is your question.

Comment: Yes, by using a popover when you click an item in the collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

All you need is calculate CGRect of your UICollectionViewCell position. 
Note that this calculation may vary depends on your collection layout.
And then you can use code similar to this:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cellRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey sorry for the timing, it has been a while and i almost forgot it to accept. Thanks a lot :)